# Problem with Javascript function not returning total sum in a for loop with if conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am writing pure javascript without any HTML and I am having trouble with one of my functions that would need to return the total "course points."

The program consists of prompting the user the # of course taken followed by the grade received which is pushed in the "grades" array. The function `calculateCP` will allow it to reiterate every element of the array and is suppose to give me the total course points given the following if conditions.

Please help why my function isn't working! The output is returning only the first element of the array, not the total sum of all elements.

```
calculateCP = () => {
  let coursePoints;
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    if (grades[i] >= 90) {
      coursePoints = 4;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 80 && grades[i] < 90) {
      coursePoints = 3;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 70 && grades[i] < 80) {
      coursePoints = 2;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 60 && grades[i] < 70) {
      coursePoints = 1;
    } else if (grades[i] < 60) {
      coursePoints = 0;
    }
    return total = total + coursePoints;
  }
}
  const grades = [];

  let noOfCourses = parseInt(prompt("Please enter # of courses taken: "));
  console.log("\n")

  for (let i = 0; i < noOfCourses; i++) {
    grades.push(prompt('Enter grade recieved '));
  }
  console.log(calculateCP());
}
```

Comment: `return` <-- that kills the function. Also your snippet is missing a closing `}` for the end of the function body.

Comment: @coderpc i don't think that code edit reproduces the intent. I think it was meant as separate snippets. As is, it would throw for using `grades` inside of TDZ, and be infinite recursion.

Comment: I removed the return and re-edited the snipped to include the closing } of the function. The output is displaying undefined...

Comment: Just to make it more clear: having the return at the end of the `for` body means, that when reaching it, the function will return. That implies the first time it runs, aka the first iteration, aka you'll only regard the first element. Remove the `return`, and do a `return total;` after the `for` loop's body.

Comment: As a side note, `else` cases will only get evaluated, if the related `if` doesn't. That means the `grades[i] < 90` and related are redundant. If `grades[i] >= 90` is `false`, then `grades[i] < 90` must already hold, unless you are dealing with `NaN`, which should be considered separately, and all of your conditions would fail anyways.

Comment: You're awesome, it works now! I spent too much time trying to figure out my error but reading your comment made me understand now what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop you just want to sum the values.. only once you're done, return the total :) something like this..

```
calculateCP = () => {
  let coursePoints;
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    if (grades[i] >= 90) {
      coursePoints = 4;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 80 && grades[i] < 90) {
      coursePoints = 3;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 70 && grades[i] < 80) {
      coursePoints = 2;
    } else if (grades[i] >= 60 && grades[i] < 70) {
      coursePoints = 1;
    } else if (grades[i] < 60) {
      coursePoints = 0;
    }
    total = total + coursePoints;
  }
  return total;
}
  const grades = [];

  let noOfCourses = parseInt(prompt("Please enter # of courses taken: "));
  console.log("\n")

  for (let i = 0; i < noOfCourses; i++) {
    grades.push(prompt('Enter grade recieved '));
  }
  console.log(calculateCP());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the return statement from the for loop and put it right after it..

change this:

```
return total = total + coursePoints;
```

to this:

```
  ... for loop
  total = total + coursePoints;
}
return total;
```